# Set multiple properties in one go, without initializer - C#

Tags: c#

I am just wondering whether it is possible.

Suppose I have an onject, and some of it's properties are already set and we can't initialize it considering set properties will be lost. I can set other properties like below

```
obj.Prop1 = value1;
obj.Prop2 = value2;
obj.Prop3 = value3;
obj.Prop4 = value4;
```

and there are lot more to set. Can I set these values in one go, like initializer? may be like

```
obj { Prop1 = value1, Prop2 = value2, Prop3 = value3, Prop4 = value4 };
```

**EDIT**

I just thought Microsoft has done few things to reduce typing effort, like

```
int a = b = c = 0;
```

Here could be another effort of them and I missed that.

Comment: Where is this different to what you want to avoid? Only a few hits to the keyboard?

Comment: Just write a method that does that for you instead.

Comment: In both ways you are doing same thing with same efforts

Comment: @HimBromBeere may be. So we do in generic initializer.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "in one go"? It is important to know what kind of behavior you're looking for here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I mean one liner here.

Comment: So one line, just remove linebreaks? `obj.Prop1 = value1; obj.Prop2 = value2; ... `, isn't that good enough then?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen believe me that was one I was missing :D

Comment: @Imad what are you trying to do? Why do you want to change multiple properties at once? This looks like a code smell - if multiple properties change together, then perhaps they should be in their own class. If you are trying to reuse an existing objec - why? Even if you *have* to reuse the same object, you can extract such properties in a separate State class and only change this class

Comment: "and there are lot more to set" There's your problem. You have one class that is trying to do too much. How many properties does it have? If more than 3-4, break it up into smaller classes, and initialise each in turn.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of an initializer is: **initialize the object at once or not at all**, so if any of the assignments fail the whole initialization should fail. Is this what you want to achieve? Then create a method that does this for you and throw an exception if anything goes wrong:

```
void SetProperties(params object[] args) {
    obj.Prop1 = args[1];
    obj.Prop2 = args[2];
    obj.Prop3 = args[3];
    obj.Prop4 = args[4];
}
```

Now call it as `SetProperties(1, 2, 3, 4);`

IN VB there is a feature called `With` when I remember right. But there is no equivalent in C# for this.

EDIT: This code however is of course quite dirty, as such an array should be validated for length and content before accessing the members within. I left this out to show you that what you want to do is simply useless.

Comment: what's the meaning if I write same code inside it, please don't think of re-usability now.

Comment: Inside it? What do you mean?

Comment: Inside method, no typing effort reduced

Comment: @Imad You care about *typing effort*? Are you writing your code in notepad?

Comment: Sure that´s the same, however it´s much cleaner to extract that specific behaviour into a new method or even a new class when all those properties belong together.

Comment: It seriously just isn't possible to downvote this answer enough. It's hard to think of a more bug-prone, fragile solution to the problem.

Comment: @Luaan No, .Net has done few thing to reduce typing effort, so I thought here also they did it and I am missing.

Comment: @DavidArno I added a hint for that. Of course you are right, I left all the checking and validation out.

Answer (score 0):

No.

C# has nothing like `with` that would allow you to do this.

Depending on what it is exactly you want, there are some ways to come closer, though. For example, if you want to set the properties as a single expression, you can always make your own helper method that runs an action and returns the reference. This is the reason why there are object initializers in the first place - not to save up on a few key presses, it's there to allow you to initialize an object in a single expression.

Comment: `with` doesn't do that either. It's just a shortcut

Comment: @panagiotisKanavos Well, it seems that's exactly what the OP wants :)

Answer (score -1):

The normal format for doing this would be

```
var o = new obj() {
    Prop1 = value1, 
    Prop2 = value2, 
    Prop3 = value3, 
    Prop4 = value4
};
```

Is that what you're after? I may be struggling with the language a bit -- do you mean you want an alternative to the normal initialization?

Comment: The object has already been created: "_Suppose I have an onject, and some of it's properties are already set and we can't initialize it considering set properties will be lost_"

Comment: @ryanyuyu actually it's the OP that mentioned this syntax. The question is *very* confusing and most likely a code smell - why change multiple properties at once? Either there should be a child class instead of multiple properties, or the OP should really be creating and initializing a new object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh I agree I have no idea what the OP wants.  But it's clear that the OP already has an existing object and can't use a new object (and the initializer) without losing the past information.

Comment: Ok, what's best for this answer then do you think? can scrub if it's not adding anything -- maybe wait for the OP to comment?

Comment: @TimBarrass yeah, I have no idea.  I'd say VTC as "unclear" based on the comments of the other potentially helpful posts.  No one has any idea what the OP really wants, and the answer "that's not possible" doesn't seems to be helping the OP.